# Javascript function anchor onclick syntax

Tags: html, syntax, hyperlink, onclick

I had following script for comment system working nicely until I put parameters into function call.  Now instead of the function executing, it just reloads the page and bumps me up to the top.  (Before, I had it not bumping and nicely inserting box.)  Can anyone see error in following.  Note, I gather that # is not preferred way to call functions from link, but other ways seemed rather complicated for this simple function call.  Many thanks.

Note thispage is a text string ie "comments.php" while id and topicid are integers.

```
<script>
function showReplyBox(id,topicid,thispage) {
    var replybox = '<form action = "newcomment.php" method = "post"><input type="hidden" name="comid" value="';
replybox = replybox+ id + '">';
replybox = replybox + '<input type="hidden" name="topicid" value="';
replybox = replybox + topicid + '">';
replybox = replybox + '<input type="hidden" name="thispage" value="';
replybox = replybox + thispage + '">';
replybox = replybox + '<textarea autofocus placeholder="Reply to comment" id="replyarea" rows=1 cols=72></textarea><br><button>Reply</button></form>';
    var empty = ""; 

document.getElementById('replybox').innerHTML = replybox;
}
</script>
<body>
//link to call function
<a href="#" onclick="showReplyBox(44,142,'comments.php');return false">Reply</a

//box inserted here
<div id="replybox"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have the function return `false` at the end to prevent the browsers default behavior of following the anchor.

Here is a working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VhYd8/

Comment: Combo of your code and javascript:void below seemed to do it.  But not until I cut and pasted code from fiddle did it work.  Something was weird in my syntax.

Answer (score 4):

replace the `#` in the anchor tag with `javascript:void(0)`

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showReplyBox(44,142,'comments.php');return false">Reply</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
//link to call function
<a href="#" id="my_a" t_id=44 t_tid=142 t_php="comments.php">Reply</a>
<script>
    function showReplyBox(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var tar_a = e.target;
        var id = tar_a .getAttribute("t_id");
        var topicid = tar_a .getAttribute("t_tid");
        var thispage = tar_a .getAttribute("t_php");

        var replybox = '<form action = "newcomment.php" method = "post"><input type="hidden" name="comid" value="';
        replybox = replybox+ id + '">';
        replybox = replybox + '<input type="hidden" name="topicid" value="';
        replybox = replybox + topicid + '">';
        replybox = replybox + '<input type="hidden" name="thispage" value="';
        replybox = replybox + thispage + '">';
        replybox = replybox + '<textarea autofocus placeholder="Reply to comment" id="replyarea" rows=1 cols=72></textarea><br><button>Reply</button></form>';
        var empty = ""; 

        document.getElementById('replybox').innerHTML = replybox;
    }
    doucument.getElementById("my_a").addEventListener('click',showReplyBox,false);
</script>
//box inserted here
<div id="replyarea"></div>
</body>
```